# How do I fix a this.o.filesVariableName is not a function using Jodit image uploader?

Tags: file-upload, editor, jodit

I'm trying to use the Jodit editor and wish to use the image uploading capabilities to specify a folder and path of where to upload it to using a PHP script.

I'm trying to put in some console.log statements to check my values, but when I select an image, I receive this error in the console which I don't know how to fix.

[image]

The code I've used in the page is:

```
<script>

var editor = new Jodit('#editor_Jodit',{
    enableDragAndDropFileToEditor: true,
    uploader: {
        url: 'connector/upload.php',
        format: 'json',
        pathVariableName: 'path',
        filesVariableName: 'images',
        prepareData: function (data) {
            return data;
        },
        isSuccess: function (resp) {
            return !resp.error;
        },
        getMsg: function (resp) {
            return resp.msg.join !== undefined ? resp.msg.join(' ') : resp.msg;
        },
        process: function (resp) {
            return {
                files: resp[this.options.uploader.filesVariableName] || [],
                path: resp.path,
                baseurl: resp.baseurl,
                error: resp.error,
                msg: resp.msg
            };
        },
        error: function (e) {
            this.events.fire('errorPopap', [e.getMessage(), 'error', 4000]);
        },
        defaultHandlerSuccess: function (data, resp) {
            var i, field = this.options.uploader.filesVariableName;
            if (data[field] && data[field].length) {
                for (i = 0; i < data[field].length; i += 1) {
                    this.selection.insertImage(data.baseurl + data[field][i]);
                }
            }
        },
        defaultHandlerError: function (resp) {
            this.events.fire('errorPopap', [this.options.uploader.getMsg(resp)]);
        }
    }
});
editor.value = '<p>start</p>';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the following line:

```
filesVariableName: 'images'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Replace with a function

```
filesVariableName: function (r) {
                    return 'images'
                },
```